# Xamarin Forms Android not installing correctly

Tags: windows, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2017 on 1 of my Windows 10 machines so I can use it as a build slave for my Xamarin.Forms project. However, it keeps failing to load Xamarin.Forms Android. I have reinstalled multiple times but to no avail. I have gotten it to work on 3 different Windows 10 computers. Any help would be appreciated.

[Error it gives me when I try to open of Xamarin.Forms Android settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kET1e.png)

Here is the relevant entries in the Activity Log the above message pointed me to.

```
<entry>
    <record>184</record>
    <time>2017/06/28 01:28:01.166</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>LegacySitePackage failed for package [XamarinAndroidPackage]Source: &apos;Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android&apos; Description: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.&#x000D;&#x000A;System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.XamarinAndroidPackage.Initialize() in C:\d\lanes\4699\fec6f88f\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\XamarinAndroidPackage.cs:line 170&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)</description>
    <guid>{296E6A4E-2BD5-44B7-A96D-8EE3D9CDA2F6}</guid>
    <hr>80004003 - E_POINTER</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
</entry>
<entry>
  <record>185</record>
  <time>2017/06/28 01:28:01.183</time>
  <type>Error</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>SetSite failed for package [XamarinAndroidPackage](null)</description>
  <guid>{296E6A4E-2BD5-44B7-A96D-8EE3D9CDA2F6}</guid>
  <hr>80004003 - E_POINTER</hr>
  <errorinfo></errorinfo>
</entry>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think your best bet is to take this up with the guys at Xamarin directly.

Comment: You could also try the visual studio uninstaller on git hub to remove all of visual studio and then install it again https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller

Comment: there might be something left over from a previous install causing issues

Comment: Unfortunately the VisualStudioUninstaller did not work. I am going to go bug Xamarin directly now. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with a guy from the Visual Studio support team but we could not figure out a solution. In the end I did the Window 10's Fresh Start and reinstalled Visual Studio. This time it worked.